# MySQL startup error - port is already in use

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I get the following error while trying to start XAMPP:

```
12:34:26 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL service...
12:34:38 PM  [mysql]    Problem detected!
12:34:38 PM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
12:34:38 PM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:34:38 PM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:34:38 PM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
12:34:38 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Comment: Error pretty clear to me, clear up port 3306 or let MySQL run on a different port.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to start MySQL when another MySQL is already running on the machine (using the same port).

Answer (score 5):

The log cleraly states that another application is listening on port 3306, so it is not possible to start MySQL since 3306 is the configured port for it (default port for MySQL connections). This application that already listens on por 3306 is another instance of MySQL that's probably configured to start automatically.

If you are using Windows, click the `Start` button, then `Execute`, then type `services.msc` and press `[Enter]`. Look for the running MySQL service, stop it, and configure it to prevent its launching on system startup. After that you should start XAMPP normally.

Comment: I have mariadb running already thats why port 3306 is in use, can I use 3307 to exposr mysql on that port?

Answer (score 4):

1. open xampp control panel.
2. click on "config" button.
3. click on "service and port settings".
4. click on "mysql" tab.
5. change the value labeled "Main Port" to 3307

Comment: If you get access denied error, then make sure you right-click on xampp and click on "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

So, mysql is listening `3306` port by default. According to your error,some service has already used it.

Depends on your OS,check who are using it. For example for `netstat -lp | grep 3306`, you can close this service and restart your mysql or change to another port `OR` you an change mysql default  port to listen in your  `my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 0):

may be you have previously installed xampp app and left in before complete installation and then reinstalled it before uninstalling previous one just uninstall privious one or uninstall both and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend told me to reinstall xampp in C drive and it did worked but after some time i was facing same problem again so i followed this steps hope it will be helpfull.
Open cmd as administrator
If there's nothing important running on port number 3306 kill that process.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks82y.jpg)

Follow this steps:
(In case photo have any error)
after opening cmd as administer run command

1. netstat -ano |findstr 3306
2. Then observe the PID at last column if there is only one process running shut it down.
3. taskkill /F /PID portidnumber

In case you get error even after doing that try to do follow the steps here:
I experienced that if we try to stop mysql before apache it is giving error.
So when you go to stop process or server stop apache first and then mysql.
And don't shutdown xampp without stopping any server

(I found this by web search and some try and error and it's working for me at least)